# Can I serialize / dserialize flatbuffers to / from JSON?

Tags: c++, json, serialization, deserialization, flatbuffers

Is it possible to serialize / deserialize flatbuffers to and from JSON?

What I really want to do is to save flatbuffers as JSON, allow people to change whatever value they want, then read back JSON into a flatbuffer (and use that in some way in the application).

Maybe there is another way to achieve the same effect. We are working in C++.

Comment: FlatBuffers work with binary data directly with no indirection.  So whats wrong with: JSON <---> Your App (Struct/Classes) <---> FlatBuffers ? if you do it other way arround, can't see the point of using FlatBuffers.  But to answer you question: I think yes : you could put JSON as chars in the flatbuffers. Dont see problem here.

Comment: Everything is possible in computer science... well almost everything. In the worst case, you can write the serializator.

Comment: @StPiere We happen to have a use case for what is stated in the OP.

Comment: @BiagioFesta Thanks for that incredible insight.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is built-in functionality in FlatBuffers. See "Text and Schema parsing" here: https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_use_cpp.html
Also see examples of that in `test.cpp` in `ParseAndGenerateTextTest()`, or also `registry.h`

Answer (score 8):

this is what I use

sample.fbs file containing flatbuffers schema.

```
table sample
{
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: int;
}

root_type sample;
```

the program that parses JSON to flatbuffers binary and back to JSON

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "flatbuffers/idl.h"

int main()
{
    std::string input_json_data = "{ \
            firstName: \"somename\", \
            lastName: \"someothername\", \
            age: 21 \
        } \
        ";

    std::string schemafile;
    std::string jsonfile;
    bool ok = flatbuffers::LoadFile("sample.fbs", false, &schemafile);
    if (!ok) {
        std::cout << "load file failed!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    flatbuffers::Parser parser;
    parser.Parse(schemafile.c_str());
    if (!parser.Parse(input_json_data.c_str())) {
        std::cout << "flatbuffers parser failed with error : " << parser.error_ << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::string jsongen;
    if (!GenerateText(parser, parser.builder_.GetBufferPointer(), &jsongen)) {
        std::cout << "Couldn't serialize parsed data to JSON!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "intput json" << std::endl
              << input_json_data << std::endl
              << std::endl
              << "output json" << std::endl
              << jsongen << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

produces following output

```
$ ./build/output/test_json_fb 
intput json
{             firstName: "somename",             lastName: "someothername",             age: 21         }         

output json
{
  firstName: "somename",
  lastName: "someothername",
  age: 21
}
```

created by referring page https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/samples/sample_text.cpp

Comment: What is the purpose of this line:
if (!parser.Parse(input_json_data.c_str()))

Answer (score 1):

http://frogermcs.github.io/json-parsing-with-flatbuffers-in-android/

FlatBuffers library is getting more and more popular recently. If you check last Android Performance Patterns series, Colt McAnlis mentions about it a couple times in different videos. Probably you remember Facebook’s announcement about migration to FlatBuffers. Also some time ago I published post about how to start using it in Android.

**java**

```
public class FlatBuffersParser {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("FlatBuffersParser");
    }

    public ByteBuffer parseJson(String json, String schema) {
        final byte[] bytes = parseJsonNative(json, schema);
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
    }

    private native byte[] parseJsonNative(String json, String schema);
}
```

**C++ **

```
#ifndef __MAIN_H__
#define __MAIN_H__

#include <flatbuffers/idl.h>
#include "main.h"

JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL
Java_frogermcs_io_flatbuffersparser_FlatBuffersParser_parseJsonNative(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                      jobject instance,
                                                                      jstring json_,
                                                                      jstring schema_) {
    const char *json = env->GetStringUTFChars(json_, 0);
    const char *schema = env->GetStringUTFChars(schema_, 0);

    flatbuffers::Parser parser;
    bool ok = parser.Parse(schema) && parser.Parse(json);

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(json_, json);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(schema_, schema);

    if (ok) {
        flatbuffers::uoffset_t length = parser.builder_.GetSize();
        jbyteArray result = env->NewByteArray(length);
        uint8_t *bufferPointer = parser.builder_.GetBufferPointer();
        env->SetByteArrayRegion(result, 0, length, reinterpret_cast<jbyte *>(bufferPointer));
        return result;
    }
}

#endif // __MAIN_H__
```